# Best practices for ios project use unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

We ios project use unity3d, but the unity3d project is in developing, and they send we new unity3d project every day, we needs to export to ios project every day, and we move our current ios project to the new exported ios project by unity3d. How do you guys do about this, we try to build the u3d ios project to static lib, we build success but use the static lib have many problems, some like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"UnityKeyboard_GetText(std::string*)", referenced from:
KeyboardOnScreen::getText() const in libiPhone-lib.a(iPhoneKeyboard.o)
"UnityAD_DestroyInterstitial(void*)", referenced from:
ADInterstitialAd_CUSTOM_Native_DestroyInterstitial(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_InterstitialAvailable()", referenced from:
ADInterstitialAd_CUSTOM_Native_InterstitialAvailable() in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_ReloadInterstitial(void*)", referenced from:
ADInterstitialAd_CUSTOM_Native_ReloadInterstitial(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_ShowInterstitial(void*)", referenced from:
ADInterstitialAd_CUSTOM_Native_ShowInterstitial(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_CreateInterstitial(bool)", referenced from:
ADInterstitialAd_CUSTOM_Native_CreateInterstitial(short) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_ShowBanner(void*, bool)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_ShowBanner(void*, short) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_BannerAdLoaded(void*)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_BannerAdLoaded(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_InterstitialAdLoaded(void*)", referenced from:
ADInterstitialAd_CUSTOM_Native_InterstitialAdLoaded(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_BannerPosition(void*, float*, float*)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_BannerPosition(void*, Vector2f*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_DestroyBanner(void*)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_DestroyBanner(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_LayoutBanner(void*, int)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_LayoutBanner(void*, int) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_BannerSize(void*, float*, float*)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_BannerSize(void*, Vector2f*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_MoveBanner(void*, float, float)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_INTERNAL_CALL_Native_MoveBanner(void*, Vector2f const&) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_BannerTypeAvailable(int)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_BannerTypeAvailable(int) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_BannerAdVisible(void*)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_BannerAdVisible(void*) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
"UnityAD_CreateBanner(int, int)", referenced from:
ADBannerView_CUSTOM_Native_CreateBanner(int, int) in libiPhone-lib.a(iAD.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a "libiPhone-lib.a" file in "Libraries" directory after you build (by unity3d).
check if the "libiPhone-lib.a" in your "Link Binary With Libraries" . if not click "+" -> 
"Add other..." -> "Libraries" select "libiPhone-lib.a" .
i fixed my errors by this .